# In react, how can I store data immediately if there's none and use it right away?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, store

I'm having trouble using LocalStorage data.

I used storejs (localStorage library), therefore `store.getItem` equals to localStorage.getItem and `store.setItem` equals to localStorage.setItem.

please check my code.

```js
const test = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const res = store.getItem('data')

    // I'm trying toexecutes following code if store returns undefined.
    if(!res) {
      store.setItem('data', [{name:'aden', age:17}])
      store.getItem('data')
    }
  },[])

return <></>

}
```

I know this code doesn't work. However, What I'm trying to do is when component mounts and there's nothing in LocalStorage, I want to immediately `setItem` to LocalStorage, and fetch the item right away.

However, with that code, I get nothing from the LocalStorage, It seems like I'm having misconception on lifecycle of react.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Make sure you don't confuse setItem with store.setItem. Also, second getItem return value is never used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Test = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));

  const addToLocalStorage = () => {
    const payload = [{ name: "aden", age: 17 }];
    setUser(payload);
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(payload));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {user?.length > 0 &&
          user.map((e) => <span key={e.name}>name:{e.name}</span>)}
      </div>
      <button onClick={addToLocalStorage}>Add to localStorage</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

useEffect(() => {
const res = store.getItem('data')

```
// I'm trying toexecutes following code if store returns undefined.
if(!res) {
  store.setItem('data', [{name:'aden', age:17}])
  store.getItem('data')
}
```

},[])
Maybe you should type store.setItem

Comment: Sorry. It is just misspelling. : /